# When removing Content Managers from Reporting Services, are there any repercussions?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have just started working with Report Services for a company and noted that none of the content managers have been removed (even if they have left the company). I was wondering if anyone knows whether there would be any repercussions if i removed or down graded their role...?

These content managers have created and deployed reports, set up security users, created folders and set up subscriptions.

I can recreate the subscriptions so that they are not under the ex-employees name, but what about the rest....

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing users from the Content Managers role will not stop or remove anything in SSRS other than those users' ability to access reports. It will not remove folders or other users.

Disabling accounts in Active Directory might disable some data sources, if they were set to use that user account to access the data. But if they were set to use a service account as the data access account, then they will continue to work, regardless of what's happened to the creating account.